# Sci-Fi Short Story: Officer Fakes Going Over To Aliens, Advises Atrocities, Fakes Death to Galvanize Humans to Fight

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It was a story where the world's military was soft, privates would all become generals, etc. He 'went over' to the alien enemy side to advise them. Told aliens a mass hanging would break resistance, knowing it would really infuriate the humans and unite them to really fight.

When he was finally cornered he launched an empty lifeboat deep into space to get it away while he ensured his body was destroyed in the alien ship. Earth forces would then retain their hatred and determination to track him down for revenge and thus stay hard and ready against other future invasions.

Comment: Uh. I have read this one - I half remember the traitor reminiscing his deeds in his wounded spaceship before killing his last surviving alien "friend" and climbing into the reactor tubes - and I tried to google some of the sentences I think I remembered (the alien saying "I think I begin to understand, and if I am right I would very much like to kill you", the commander of the boarding party saying to his men "Remember the words of Professor...", the sergeant concluding "...the next aliens, in case *he* got to them first") but to no avail. Will keep banging my head.

Comment: @Lorendiac You are right. I had finally managed to find one of the sentences I half remembered ("And if it is what I think it is, I think I would like to kill you") and I saw your comment. The story *is* definitely that one, so you may want to post it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you both. That is the exact one. I found an audio of it online and found a key line that confirmed it was the one, and the ending as you described it was also clearly the same story. Wow, glad I finally thought to post this question. Between this forum and some spooky luck in wandering used bookstores, I think I've found all the most memorable short stories I remember so well from reading decades ago. Thanks again.